# OpenFileDialog does not contain a definition for InitialDirectory

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, openfiledialog

I've inherited a Silverlight 5-project which uses an `OpenFileDialog`. When I open the project in VS 2012 I get the error:

> Error  513 `System.Windows.Controls.OpenFileDialog` does not contain a definition for `InitialDirectory` and no extension method `InitialDirectory` accepting a first argument of type `System.Windows.Controls.OpenFileDialog` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The project was created in VS 2010 with the Silverlight 5 SDK installed and it still builds in VS 2010, but I want it to work in VS 2012.
The project upgraded successfully when I opened it in VS 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Silverlight 5 SDK for VS 2010 and now it builds in VS 2012.